# What is the correct way for comparing dates for equality?

Tags: java, date

I am currently working on the migration to microservice from a legacy API. The legacy API does date comparison for equality by using strings.

Example

```
String date1FromDataSource1 = "20221110";
String date2FromDataSource2 = "2022-11-10:00:00.000";

String data2FromDataSource2Formatted = formatDateAsPerDataSource1(date1FromDataSource2);

Boolean areDatesEqual = data1FromDataSource1.equals(data2FromDataSource2Formatted);
```

Should I continue pursuing this way or convert them both to ZoneDateTime and do the date compare.

Comment: If this is a migration I think you should implement a logic that is exactly equivalent to the existing one. If the existing one is faulty, make sure the new one has the same faults.

Comment: I would normalize both dates into `LocalDateTime` objects and compare them.

Comment: I agree with @Mr.Polywhirl that you should use Date-Time API rather than String API/; otherwise, you will keep struggling with inventing new Regex expressions for even the slightest change in the formats.

Comment: What does `2022-11-10:00:00.000` signify? Are you sure that your format after the date has got 2 digits, 2 digits and 3 digits?? What are they? Also are they required to be zeroes for the dates to be considered equal, or could they have other values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation doesn't matter.
Only the system tests matter.

There should be enough system tests for the legacy system that if they pass, the service is ready to deploy to production. If there aren't enough, write more until that is true.

System tests are implementation independent and completely portable. Pick the simplest implementation you can think of. If the system tests pass for your new system, your implementation is good.

Unit tests *are* implementation dependent and should be written too. Quality ensured, with unit and system tests passing and you're good to deploy.

As for a suggestion for an implementation, since you're dealing with strings, you could just compare them as strings.

Here's a starter implementation:

```java
public boolean areSame(String date1, String date2) {
    return yyyymmdd(date1).equals(yyyymmdd(date2));
}

/* @return the first 8 digits found in str */
private String yyyymmdd(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\D", "").substring(0, 8);
}
```

Comment: *The implementation doesn't matter.* I beg to differ. The first and most important virtue of the implementation is that it is clearly readable. The second is that it is correct it. Because: If incorrect and readable, you can correct. If correct today and unreadable, when a different requirement comes in tomorrow, you have to throw it away.

Comment: @OleV.V. poor choice of words on my part. "Doesn't matter" meant "use any approach that works". It's also flexible - you're allowed to change it without breaking the service. Code quality, such as readability, modularity, etc is of course always important, but it's orthogonal to the implementation/algorithm choice.